# Dynamically play the latest video in Asset Library

Tags: modern-experience, video, asset-library

In our SharePoint Online tenant, i would like to dynamically play (in a modern script editor webpart) the latest video uploaded to one of the asset libraries.

I was able to find ways to play a static video by providing the URL but not sure how to achieve the same for any latest video uploaded dynamically.

Any suggestions or guidance is much appreciated to achieve this.

I would like to play the video using a modern script editor webpart, but any other available options also i can consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Classic pages, was able to achieve this using "Content Query Webpart" but for modern pages, could not find any solution.